# extension method as a way to rename property

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods

Some class has ugly field called URL, but Id rather call it file.

```
public static void setFile(this AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer mp, string filename) {
    mp.URL = filename;
}
```

and

```
public static string file(this AxWMPLib.AxWindowsMediaPlayer mp) {
     return mp.URL;
}
```

Is there any way to not use setFile, but make file act like property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you're after is extension properties, [which don't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138367/most-wanted-feature-for-c-4-0#138378). The extension methods require () to follow the method name when called.